# Updating several records at once in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a rails 2 app I'm building, I have a need to update a collection of records with specific attributes. I have a named scope to find the collection, but I have to iterate over each record to update the attributes. Instead of making one query to update several thousand records, I'll have to make several thousand queries.

What I've found so far is something like `Model.find_by_sql("UPDATE products ...)`

This feels really junior, but I've googled and looked around SO and haven't found my answer.

For clarity, what I have is:

```
ps = Product.last_day_of_freshness
ps.each { |p| p.update_attributes(:stale => true) }
```

What I want is:

```
Product.last_day_of_freshness.update_attributes(:stale => true)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [ActiveRecord::Base.update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class) - from the documentation:

> Updates all records with details given if they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.

```
Product.last_day_of_freshness.update_all(:stale => true)
```

Actually, since this is rails 2.x (You didn't specify) - the named_scope chaining may not work, you might need to pass the conditions for your named scope as the second parameter to update_all instead of chaining it onto the end of the Product scope.

Comment: update_all is only available on Rails 3 - the question is unfortunately about Rails 2.

Comment: @Taryn East not true, `update_all` was moved from ActiveRecord::Base to ActiveRecord::Relation between rails 2.3.x and 3.0 - I have updated the link and added a comment to clarify.

Comment: oh man, embarrassing. Yeah, that's what I'm looking for. I swear I RTFM before posting :)

Comment: @Bryce Haha no worries, there's too much manual to read it all if you want to get anything done ;)

Comment: @BrettBender chrs mate but is there a version of update_all which also checks validation rules?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon Well it has been a while since I used Rails but this method doesn't. There is a lot of overhead to casting the value appropriately and running validations, so it will be a lot slower. If you need all that, I would suggest looping over all the records you intend on updating and calling save on each manually. Please leave a comment if you find a better way though!

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using `update_all` ?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all

Answer (score 6):

For those who will need to update big amount of records, one million or even more, there is a good way to update records by batches.

```
product_ids = Product.last_day_of_freshness.pluck(:id)
iterations_size = product_ids.count / 5000

puts "Products to update #{product_ids.count}"

product_ids.each_slice(5000).with_index do |batch_ids, i|
  puts "step #{i} of iterations_size"
  Product.where(id: batch_ids).update_all(stale: true)
end
```

If your table has a lot indexes, it also will increase time for such operations, because it will need to rebuild them. When I called `update_all` for all records in table, there were about two million records and twelve indexes, operation didn't accomplish in more than one hour. With this approach it took about 20 minutes in development env and about 4 minutes in production, of course it depends on application settings and server hardware. You can put it in `rake task` or some background worker.

Answer (score 2):

Loos like update_all is the best option... though I'll maintain my hacky version in case you're curious:

You can use just plain-ole SQL to do what you want thus:

```
ps = Product.last_day_of_freshness
ps_ids = ps.map(%:id).join(',') # local var just for readability
Product.connection.execute("UPDATE `products` SET `stale` = TRUE WHERE id in (#{ps_ids)")
```

Note that this is db-dependent - you may need to adjust quoting style to suit.

Comment: It is extremely unwise to perform string interpolations within a query string.

Comment: This was written in 2011. Keep that in mind and update it accordingly :)